# Inflate multiple layout in FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui, recyclerview-layout

I'm trying to inflate atleast two layout in FirestoreRecyclerAdapter but it seems there is no declaration in FirestoreRecyclerAdapter for dual layout, because I'm facing problem on onCreateViewHolder(), take a look:

```
  @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            if (viewType == TYPE_ONE){
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item_layout, viewGroup, false);
                return new MainCategoryHolder(view);
            }else if (viewType == TYPE_TEST){
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_layout_item, viewGroup, false);
                return new TestLayoutHolder(view);
            }

        }
```

Here is what I'm getting:

**'onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int)' in 'Anonymous class derived from com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter' clashes with 'onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int)' in 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter'; attempting to use incompatible return type**

I know what error says but, what is the alternatives of this, it is piece of cake with the normal recyclerview via using the same getItemViewType, but I can not find a way to implement for FirestoreRecyclerAdapter, is it even possible?

Here is my **getItemViewType()**

```
  @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (position % 2 == 0){
                return TYPE_TEST;
            }else {
                return TYPE_ONE;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You now need to overwrite getItemViewType and put your logic for which view should be what type and when, it will call getItemViewType first and then push that result into the onCreateViewHolder, much like using payloads for standard recyclerViewd

Comment: but what would be the return type of the onCreateViewHolder?

Comment: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, as all your viewHolders should extend RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Comment: I have updated the question, let me know if that is right?

Comment: Brandon, if you care to write a piece of code for me, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this.